# assignin('caller',...) within a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

I created this very useful bit of code to assign variables dynamically from a struct :

```
function getParam(param)
% this function extracts the fields of structure param and assigns them
% to variables of corresponding names in the caller workspace
allFieldsParam = fieldnames(param);
for iField = 1:length(allFieldsParam)
  assignin('caller',allFieldsParam{iField},param.(allFieldsParam{iField}));
end
```

The problem is that when I call getParam within a function, sometimes it works and sometimes it returns an error of the form :

```
??? Error using ==> assignin
Attempt to add "blocksizes" to a static workspace.
 See MATLAB Programming, Restrictions on Assigning to Variables
 for details.

    Error in ==> getParam at 7
      assignin('caller',allFieldsParam{iField},param.(allFieldsParam{iField}));

    Error in ==> classif_nmf_db at 15
    getParam(param);
```

Anyone has a clue how I can fix this ?

Regards
AL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to enforce a good programming practice in MATLAB.

The document you are referred to is located here:
[Nested functions: Restrictions on Assigning to Variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html#f4-75258)

> The scoping rules for nested, and in some cases anonymous, functions
>   require that all variables used within the function be present in the
>   text of the code. Adding variables to the workspace of this type of
>   function at run time is not allowed.
>
> MATLAB issues an error if you attempt to dynamically add a variable to
>   the workspace of an anonymous function, a nested function, or a
>   function that contains a nested function. ...

Loren also has a [blog entry](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/16/nested-functions-and-variable-scope/) about it.

---

**UPDATE**

Have a look on this File Exchange submission:
[Pack & Unpack variables to & from structures with enhanced functionality (v2struct)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/file_infos/31532-pack-unpack-variables-to-from-structures-with-enhanced-functionality).