# Matlab assignin caller's caller

Tags: matlab, scope

To reduce boilerplate code in new functions I have a function `assignInput(aStruct)` (much akin to this [`getParam`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270904/assignincaller-within-a-function-in-matlab)).

For structuring, I would like to put the call to `assignin` in a sub function.
Currently `assignin` is called as `assignin('caller', ...` .

When nesting, the `'caller'`-scope becomes that of `assignInput` instead of that of `assignInput`'s caller.

Is it possible to assign to a workspace '2 levels' up?

I have tried wrapping the call to `assignin` in an `evalin`, like

```
evalin('caller','assignin(''caller'',...
```

But I get an error for attempting to assign in static workspace.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that. you can only `assignin` or `evalin` in either `'caller'` or `'base'`. You might want to look into nested functions

Comment: I tried making the sub function nested, since _some_ variables are shared with the nesting function. But it isn't exactly the actual workspace.